# Keep IE7 and IE8 both on single PC, single user

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to test a website on IE8 and I have my company's Bug tracking website which works ONLY on IE7 and previous versions of IE (hence I only have IE7 on my PC). So, if I wanna test for IE8, I can't upgrade IE7 to IE8. So, how can I keep IE7 on my PC, but still test for IE8 and other versions of IE?
I have already referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761804/how-do-i-get-ie7-to-emulate-ie8). But I don't know how to use Mordernizr. Is it possible to keep both IE7 and IE8 on a single PC, single user???

Comment: ok..will keep that in mind

Comment: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer IETester. I just download it and can test any version of IE. Here is the link of IETester
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage.
Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 6):

you can download IE9 from this link:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?WT.mc_id=MSCOM_EN_US_HP_SUPPORTHOME_131I1ENUS21314

after download and install, you have IE7, IE8 and IE9 in your system.
just run IE and press F12 key, then click on Browser Mode: IE9, and choose IE version that you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can use IETestr and test your site in IE online.
but better way to have any version of IE is IE9 and change version of its local!

Answer (score 1):

You can test your website with [Spoon](https://spoon.net/browsers/) or [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Or check this [thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-can-i-test-my-web-site-in-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sandboxie](http://sandboxie.com) to install Internet Explorer 8 in a sandbox. That way the installation of IE8 will not overwrite the old IE7 installation and you should be able to run both in parallel.

Another option is to create a virtual machine with [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). I would recommend virtual machines to web developers anyway, because it allows to test websites not just on other browsers but also on entirely different operating systems.